# How to list articles written by a certain author in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, backend

I work on a simple news web application.

It has table Articles(id,title,content,user_id) and table Users(id,name,username,passwd..), among others.

In a backend app, I would like to list only articles having a certain `user_id`.

The `user_id` I would get from `$this->getUser()->getAttribute('user_id')`.

Documentation provided at symfony web site does not cover this issue as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://symfony-world.blogspot.fr/2010/03/custom-query-for-admin-generator.html) will give you different approaches.

Regarding your needs, you can override `buildQuery`:

```
protected function buildQuery()
{
  return parent::buildQuery()
    ->where('user_id = ?', $this->getUser()->getAttribute('user_id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- in you generator.yml insert a new row under like:

  ```
  list:
    title: Articles list
    table_method: getArticlesByUserId
  ```
- in you ArticleTable.class.php insert a new function:

  ```
  public function getArticlesByUserId() {
    $userId = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute( 'user_id' );
    $u = $this->createquery( 'u' )->where( 'u.user_id = ?', $userId );  

    return $q;
  }
  ```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use [sfContext::getInstance()](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/) in the model.

Comment: The second answer, regarding the ArticlesTable.class turns out to be better for my particular need. I want to display author's real name and Category name instead of IDs. It generates far less queries because I used innerJoin-s instead of adding methods to Article.class to populate mentioned fields. Thanks.

Comment: So, which is in your opinion the best way for retrieve the UserObject id from, from example, the ArticleTable.class.php?